# Returning value adjacent to two search criteria

Tags: vba, excel

I require finding values adjacent to two search criteria from a table like this:

[image]

The code I wrote is:

```
Dim mAin As Worksheet
Dim findc As Range
Dim findsc As Range
Dim code As Long
Dim scode As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim ttlrw As Long

i = 1
Set mAin = ActiveSheet
ttlrw = mAin.Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Count

Do
    code = mAin.Cells(i, 5).Value
    scode = mAin.Cells(i, 6).Value

    Set findc = mAin.Columns(1).Find(code)
    Set findsc = mAin.Columns(2).Find(scode)
    Do
        Set findc = mAin.Columns(1).FindNext(findc)
        Set findsc = mAin.Columns(2).FindNext(findsc)
    Loop Until findc.Row = findsc.Row

    mAin.Cells(i, 7).Value = findsc.Offset(0, 1).Value
    i = i + 1
Loop Until i = ttlrw + 1
```

The values found are supposed to be output adjacent to a similar looking table, except more jumbled up.

Also the macro goes into an infinite loop after row 5.

I managed to tackle this using INDEX, MATCH, &s and turning it into an array formula; but I also would like to further improve my VBA understanding.

Comment: It would be a lot easier to answer your question if you provided sample input data and expected output. Also, your code does not check if the searched values are found at all.

Comment: You should watch this video series on Youtube:[Excel VBA Introduction](the wise owl tutorials).  Download [Smart Indenter](http://www.oaltd.co.uk/indenter/indentpage.asp); it will format you code for you.  Proper indenting makes it easy to find unclosed code blocks.

Comment: Thanks, I'll be sure to check them out. And work on my indenting, I can't even tell if it's unclosed when looking at it again.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of ways to do what you want.

```
Sub Example1_ForLoop()

    Dim lastRow As Long, x As Long
    Dim Criteria1 As Variant, Criteria2 As Variant

    Criteria1 = 2134
    Criteria2 = "003"

    lastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    For x = 1 To lastRow
        If Cells(x, 1) = Criteria1 And Cells(x, 2) = Criteria2 Then

            Cells(x, 6) = Cells(x, 3)

        End If

    Next

End Sub


Sub Example2_ForEachLoop()

    Dim c As Range, SearchRange As Range
    Dim Criteria1 As Variant, Criteria2 As Variant

    Criteria1 = 2134
    Criteria2 = "003"

    Set SearchRange = Range("A1", Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))

    For Each c In SearchRange
        If c = Criteria1 And c.Offset(0, 1) = Criteria2 Then

            c.Offset(0, 5) = c.Offset(0, 3)

        End If

    Next

End Sub

'Here is the proper way to use Find and FindNext.

Sub Example3_DoLoop_Find_FindNext()

    Dim c As Range, SearchRange As Range
    Dim firstAddress As String
    Dim Criteria1 As Variant, Criteria2 As Variant

    Criteria1 = 2134
    Criteria2 = "003"

    Set SearchRange = Range("A1", Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))

    Set c = SearchRange.Find(Criteria1, LookIn:=xlValues)

    If Not c Is Nothing Then
        firstAddress = c.Address
        Do

            If c = Criteria1 And c.Offset(0, 1) = Criteria2 Then

                c.Offset(0, 5) = c.Offset(0, 3)

            End If

            Set c = SearchRange.FindNext(c)
        Loop While Not c Is Nothing And c.Address <> firstAddress
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: To be honest, I've never used "For" arguments. Having just started, I've been making my way with IFs and Loops. But seems pretty straightforward to use! Thanks.

Comment: @Jo_Ash I updated my answer to include examples of `For`, `For Each`, and `Do` loops.  `For` loops are used when you know the exact beginning and end of the loop.  `Do` and `While` are better when you are not sure when the loop should end.

Comment: Thanks, I'm having some trouble understanding some but probably still new so need more time. 
Btw, how do I have it continuously find all the criterias (rather than a single value). Is it possible with For Arguments? And instead of having a msgbox display the output, can I change the code to have it output the values to the right of criteria 1 and 2?

Comment: What are the criteria? What values do you want to output?  Are you comparing two lists?

Comment: In my image, the values in Column A is a code representing a group, with each group having several identification numbers (in column B). For each category-id combination there's a value assigned to it in column C. Columns D and E are a bunch of generated combinations that I'm using to test whether my code worked, and Column F is supposed to be where its output. 

Sorry for all the confusion thus far and thanks for the help.
Really really appreciate the effort and patience when I'm not sure how to explain my situation.

Comment: No problem. There is a lot to learn.  It take time and repetition.

Comment: I updated my Answer to place the value of Column C in Column F if Columns' A & B meet the criteria.  I still don't know the source of the criteria or the expected output.

Comment: The source of the crtieria are the values in columns D and E, where the output comes from the values in column C that corresponds to the criteria in A and B.

Like, if value in column D and E equals to that in columns A and B respectively, then output the value in C (in the same row as the matched A and B) to column F (in the row of the searched value in D and E). Is that clearer? Or does it help too if I mention that columns A, B and C are sort of a database and the columns D and E are generated regularly and requires inserting the corresponding values of C.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
Option Explicit

Sub mAin()
    Dim mAin As Worksheet
    Dim cell As Range

    With Worksheets("mAin") '<--| '<-- change "mAin" with your actual sheet name
        .Rows(1).Insert '<--| insert a dummy header row, it'll be eventually removed
        .Cells(1, 1).Resize(, 2).Value = Array("head1", "head2") '<--| write dummy headers
        With .Range("A1:B" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row) '<--| reference its range in columns A:B from row 1 to column "A" last non empty cell row
            For Each cell In .Parent.Columns(5).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants) '<-- loop through column "E" non empty cells
                .AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:=cell.Value 'operator:=xlAnd, '<--| filter referenced range on its 1st column with current cell value
                .AutoFilter field:=2, Criteria1:=cell.Offset(, 1).Value 'operator:=xlAnd, '<--| filter referenced range again on its 2nd column with current cell adjacent column value
                If Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(103, .Cells.Resize(, 1)) > 1 Then '<--| if any cell other than header ones has been filtered...
                    cell.Offset(, 2) = .Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells(1, 3) '<--| copy current cell offseted 2 columns value to column "G"
                End If
                .Parent.AutoFilterMode = False '<--| show all rows back
            Next cell
        End With
        .Rows(1).Delete '<--| remove dummy header row
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: There are a lot of things I haven't seen before or understand. Will try it out after I try understanding it. Thanks lots!

Comment: You are welcome. I commented the code so you have a "guide" to unserstand it. Let me know.

Comment: @Jo_Ash, did you get through it?

Comment: Hey @user3598756, sorry it's been nothing short of hell at work this week. My vba learnings were supposed to be recreational whenever I was free, using objectives at work as assignments. Haven't got around to tackling the problem as is, but I did have a sort of workaround (got the idea from match and index). Don't have the exact code atm but basically I did an if-loop and combining the 2 strings together; doing until the last column + 1 (dk why I needed the one).

Comment: sorry @user3598756 about having you write the code and all. I'm going to revisit it once the workload subsides and do it properly though! Have learnt how inefficient the if loop is when my set data comes into thousands (that and the computer at work being really slow). Now I'm supposed to tackle another problem and I'm supposed to give it priority since I can't solve it with just besting formulas - need to, from an active cell onwards, copy the range till the last non-blank and paste it below the last filled cell (i.e. Duplicating data).

Comment: I'd say you could jump out of my code in much less time and much more effective results than keep on struggling with all that _Match&Index_ stuff. Anyhow suit yourself and get back when you'll make your mind up to my code. As for the new question you must make a new post